# How to analyze changed history in Git

Tags: git

We use Git in a  "god repository" workflow -- one server and repo (the GR) are the official history and people collaborate as they like, pushing to the god server when commits are ready.

Recently a colleague had a problem.  They had pushed some commits on the GR's `maintenance` branch, but their colleague had pulled and couldn't see the changes.

Me, I figured the guy didn't really push, or had pushed to the wrong repository, or something like that.  I log in to his account, navigate to the repository, do git status, and see that indeed everything is up to date.  I do a `git fetch`, and I see origin/maintenance has a `forced update` message next to it.

I do a merge and push and everything is fine -- except that it seems that someone changed the history on the GR, which is a no no (except for occasionally moving a tag).

Is there anything I can do to try to figure out where the history changed, how it changed, and who did it?

Comment: If someone really rewrote the history of the `maintenance` branch, then everyone should see errors when either trying to pull from it _or_ push to it.  That you didn't mention any such errors seems strange to me, making me think that perhaps something else is going on here.

Comment: Not necessarily.  Take a repo A and put some history into it.  Clone A into B and C.  Take B, reset back a few and push --force.  Now go into a repo C and do git pull.  All you see is that you have several unpushed commits, no errors (and a forced update tag during the fetch part of the pull).

Comment: Good point there, but the OP described someone _pushing_ some commits, which no one else could see.

Comment: You might find it beneficial to compare the God Repository in its current state to its nightly backups to see when things changed.

Comment: You could use `git reflog` from that individual's machine, but at that point you might as well run `history` too.